# Check Hbase row exist in using MapReduce to import data into Hbase

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I have a table called Table1 in Hbase with collection rows like this

```
<Image_Id, <float,float,.....>>
```

with Image_Id represents for image id and following with a sequence of float numbers.

Then I want to read this table data, processing then store new value to another table (Suppose the new table called Table 2 and be empty at the first time).

I implement this task using MapReduce

```
TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob(
            "Table1",      // input table
            scan,             // Scan instance to control CF and attribute selection
            MyMapper.class,   // mapper class
            null,             // mapper output key
            null,             // mapper output value
            job);
        TableMapReduceUtil.initTableReducerJob(
            "Table2",      // output table
            null,             // reducer class
            job);
        job.setNumReduceTasks(0);
```

For example in mapper

```
public static class MyMapper extends TableMapper<ImmutableBytesWritable, Put>  {

        public void map(ImmutableBytesWritable row, Result value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
          //read data in table 1 here
        }
    }
```

Suppose after I read a value in each row in Table 1, then I will hash it like

```
int hcode = hash(GetRowValue())
```

and then insert this hode to Table2 like this

```
context.write(hcode, Image_ID);
```

with row key is the hashcode, and the value is Image_ID corresponding in Table 1

The problem is that if hcode is similar with others before, I will update this row in Table 2 in form of `<hashCode, <Image_ID1, Image_ID2>>` by using List<> to storing list of value. To do it i will check whether or not the rowkey exists in Table 2 or not then insert a new one or update the current row.

But after running my code, I see that only after MapReduce finished, then Table2 will be filled data. During the MapReduce progress, table 2 is still empty.

**Edited**: So is there any way to implement a workflow like check exists of a row in Hbase table and then update its value while using Mapreduce?

Comment: You described many problems but didn't point out where you need help exactly.

Comment: Please refer to my edited question.